# JScrollPane won't scroll down to properly display JTextPane called from ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I want to refresh my ColorPane defined as follow:

```
public class ColorPane extends JTextPane{
    /* FYI, The function below allows me to add text with ANSI Coloring */
    public void appendANSI(String s) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

In this next `while` statement, I write `line` in a console-style window.
So as a console, I want to refresh and **scroll down automatically** at bottom when a new line is added to `textPane`.

I want to launch the following loop by pressing a `mainButton`.

```
public class mainButton implements ActionListener  {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        ColorPane textPane = new ColorPane();

        /* FYI, in is a BufferedReader */
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

            /* Add automatically in the console window */
            textPane.appendANSI(line+"\n");

            /* Last possible workaround I tried
               Which as the same effect than commenting these lines.. */
            JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());

            /* I also tried : */
            // textPane.setCaretPosition(textPane.getDocument().getLength());

            /* Or this : */
            // Rectangle rec = GenerationWindow.textPane.getVisibleRect();
            // rec.setLocation((int) (rec.getX() + 1000), (int) rec.getY());
            // textPane.scrollRectToVisible(rec);

            /* Refresh the display */
            textPane.update(textPane.getGraphics());
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, my window is scrolled down, but **only when exiting `actionPerformed`**. Why ?

In one hand I can see that the text is updated at each loop turn, but in the other hand, the `JScrollPane scrollPane` is scrolled down on end of the function...

I think I miss some swing philosophy here..

I've been roaming for hours on Oracle Documentation and StackO topics, trying different "solutions", but I'm a bit desperate now..

A console not automatically scrolling down is.. well.. not a console..

Comment: Try scrolling your pane on a separate thread from your loop

Comment: I tried to open a new Thread in each loop turn and scroll from the Thread, but it didn't work :(

Comment: I would go with camickr's suggestion. Have the while loop on the separate thread

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
textPane.update(textPane.getGraphics());
```

Don't manually invoke update(...) on a components. Swing will determine when the component needs to be repainted.

> The thing is, my window is scrolled down, but only when exiting actionPerformed. Why ?

You code is executing in a loop which is executing on the Event Dispatch Thread which is the Thread that paints the GUI. The GUI can't repaint itself until the loop is finished.

The long running code needs to execute on a separate Thread and then when you update the text pane the GUI is free to repaint itself.

I would probably use a `Swing Worker` for this thread then you can "publish" the results as they become available. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples of using a SwingWorker.

Comment: You said _"Swing will determine when the component needs to be repainted"_. But I want to controll it and refresh when **I** want :/. Moreover, I can see it's working to add line in the TextPane as soon as they are read on the buffer, so I don't get why it couldn't scroll down in the same time :/

Comment: It was long and painful but I finally did it... Many thanks it helped a lot. At the beginning, I did not understand _"You code is executing in a loop which is executing on the Event Dispatch Thread"_, but that's because of **implements ActionListener**. Information taken [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) : _It's useful to think of the code running on the event dispatch thread as a series of short tasks. Most tasks are invocations of event-handling methods, such as ActionListener.actionPerformed._

Answer (score 1):

As @camickr suggested, run the content of your actionPerformed() in a SwingWorker. Its contents should contain something like this:

```
    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           textPane.appendANSI(line+"\n");
           textpane.setCaretPosition(textpane.getDocument().getLength());
        }
    }
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        SwingUtilities.invokelater( runner );
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass some arguments like `line` to the runner ?